# CGROUPS implementation version used by docker

Tags: docker, process, linux-kernel, containers, amazon-ecs

Control groups was originally implemented in Linux kernel in 2007.

This version 1 implementation was replaced by version 2 implementation in Linux kernel 4.5.

Version 2 fixed some limitations associated with version 1 implementation.

Both CGROUPS implementations co-exist in Linux kernel

---

Does docker make use of version 1 implementation?

Comment: I would say v1: https://www.spritle.com/blogs/2019/11/11/how-to-make-docker-work-on-fedora-os-31-with-cgroups-v2/

Answer (score 2):

Docker uses v1.  You can track the work to support v2 [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40360).

Comment: With regards to `memory` CGROUP subsystem, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-memory) in this syntax `"ContainerDefinitions":[{Memory:500}]` property of `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`, are we referring to physical address space(or virtual address space) of container process?

Comment: Neither? That's a quantity of memory, not an address.